# Flatmap() keeping parent and child both JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I have this array in which some obj's dont have children I want flatten it.

```
export const Array = [
  {
    id: "1",
    title: "Dashboard 1",
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    title: "Dashboard 2",
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    title: "Dashboard 3",
  },
 {
    id: "10",
    title: "Dashboard 7",
    subNav: [
      {
        id: "11",
        title: "Dashboard 4",
      },
      {
        id: "12",
        title: "Dashboard 5",
      },
    ],
  },
```

My Code :

```
Array.flatMap(item => item.subNav ? item.subNav?.flatMap(item1 => item1) : item)
```

output :

```
[{id: '1', title: 'Dashboard 1'},
{id: '2', title: 'Dashboard 2'},
{id: '3', title: 'Dashboard 3'},
{id: '11', title: 'Dashboard 4'} ,
{id: '12', title: 'Dashboard 5']
```

What I expected :

```
[{id: '1', title: 'Dashboard 1'},
{id: '2', title: 'Dashboard 2'},
{id: '3', title: 'Dashboard 3'},
{id: '10', title: 'Dashboard 7'} ,
{id: '11', title: 'Dashboard 4'} ,
{id: '12', title: 'Dashboard 5']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If navigation is just one level deep, like shown in the example you could use the following:

```
const result = navs.flatMap(({ subNav = [], ...nav }) => [nav, ...subNav]);
```

```js
const navs = [
  { id: "1", title: "Dashboard 1" },
  { id: "2", title: "Dashboard 2" },
  { id: "3", title: "Dashboard 3" },
  {
    id: "10",
    title: "Dashboard 7",
    subNav: [
      { id: "11", title: "Dashboard 4" },
      { id: "12", title: "Dashboard 5" },
    ],
  },
];

const result = navs.flatMap(({ subNav = [], ...nav }) => [nav, ...subNav]);
console.log(result);
```

If there can be more then one level of depth you'll have to use recursion:

```
function flattenNavs(navs) {
  return navs.flatMap(({ subNav = [], ...nav }) => [nav, ...flattenNavs(subNav)]);
}

const result = flattenNavs(navs);
```

```js
const navs = [
  { id: "1", title: "Dashboard 1" },
  { id: "2", title: "Dashboard 2" },
  { id: "3", title: "Dashboard 3" },
  {
    id: "10",
    title: "Dashboard 7",
    subNav: [
      { id: "11", title: "Dashboard 4" },
      {
        id: "12",
        title: "Dashboard 5",
        subNav: [
          { id: "13", title: "further nested" },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];

function flattenNavs(navs) {
  return navs.flatMap(({ subNav = [], ...nav }) => [nav, ...flattenNavs(subNav)]);
}

const result = flattenNavs(navs);
console.log(result);
```

Both answers rely on [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring) to unpack each array element.

The `subNav` property in each element is stored in the `subNav` parameter. If it's not present we'll use an empty array as the default value. All other properties are stored in the `nav` parameter.

After unpacking (aka destructuring) the element we want to return both the `nav` and its `subNav` items on the same level. To achieve this we'll return `[nav, ...subNav]`. This will return an array with `nav` as the first element, then all `subNav` elements are appended. See: [Spread syntax (`...`): Spread in array literals - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_array_literals)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't include the parent in the results

```js
const array = [
  {
    id: "1",
    title: "Dashboard 1",
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    title: "Dashboard 2",
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    title: "Dashboard 3",
  },
  {
    id: "10",
    title: "Dashboard 7",
    subNav: [
      {
        id: "11",
        title: "Dashboard 4",
      },
      {
        id: "12",
        title: "Dashboard 5",
      },
    ],
  },
];

const result = array.flatMap(({ subNav, ...rest }) =>
  [rest, ...(subNav?.flat() || [])]
);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) were you spread ([`...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)) the object to
2 parts, the `subNav` (if existing) and the `main` object that remains

Then you can `return` that that, again, with spread syntax on the `subNav`, with a fallback (`subNav || []`) should there be no `subNav`

```js
const Array = [{id: "1", title: "Dashboard 1", }, {id: "2", title: "Dashboard 2", }, {id: "3", title: "Dashboard 3", }, {id: "10", title: "Dashboard 7", subNav: [{id: "11", title: "Dashboard 4", }, {id: "12", title: "Dashboard 5", }, ], }, ]
  
const res = Array.flatMap(({ subNav, ...main }) => [ main, ...(subNav || [] ) ]);
  
console.log(res)
```

```json
[
  {"id": "1",  "title": "Dashboard 1"}, 
  {"id": "2",  "title": "Dashboard 2"},
  {"id": "3",  "title": "Dashboard 3"},
  {"id": "10", "title": "Dashboard 7"},
  {"id": "11", "title": "Dashboard 4"},
  {"id": "12", "title": "Dashboard 5"}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can tweak your code to use a second `Array#flatMap` like so:

```js
const 
    arr = [ { id: "1", title: "Dashboard 1", }, { id: "2", title: "Dashboard 2", }, { id: "3", title: "Dashboard 3", }, { id: "10", title: "Dashboard 7", subNav: [ { id: "11", title: "Dashboard 4", }, { id: "12", title: "Dashboard 5" } ] } ], 
    
    newArr = arr.flatMap(item => item.subNav ? [item].flatMap(({subNav,...rest}) => [rest,...subNav]) : item);

console.log( newArr );
```